# How to use the return function but avoid repetition of a function?

Tags: python, return, python-3.4

Trying to write this salary calculator script, but the output keeps on calculating taxes twice. It does what it is supposed to do, but I am misusing the concept of return statement, I reckon. I am kinda new to Python and just starting with the DSA. I tried searching for this problem a lot but apart from info for return statement, I couldnt solve this recurring statement problem. I would like your suggestions on the rest of the program as well.

Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
import math

# Personal Details
name = input("Enter your first name: ")
position= input("Enter your job position: ")

def regPay():
#Computes regular hours weekly pay
    hwage= float(input("Enter hourly wage rate: "))
    tothours=int(input("Enter total regular hours you worked this week: "))
    regular_pay= float(hwage * tothours)
    print ("Your regular pay for this week is: ", regular_pay)
    return hwage, regular_pay

def overTime(hwage, regular_pay):
#Computes overtime pay and adds the regular to give a total
    totot_hours= int(input("Enter total overtime hours this week: "))
    ot_rate = float(1.5 * (hwage))
    otpay= totot_hours * ot_rate 
    print("The total overtime pay this week is: " ,otpay )
    sum = otpay + regular_pay 
    print("So total pay due this week is: ", sum)
    super_pay = float((9.5/100)*sum)
    print ("Your super contribution this week is:",super_pay)
    return super_pay 

def taxpay():
#Computes the taxes for different income thresholds, for resident Aussies.
    x = float(input("Enter the amount of your yearly income: "))

    while True:
        total = 0 
        if x  < 18200:
            print("Congrats! You dont have to pay any tax! :)")

            break 
        elif 18201 < x < 37000:
            total = ((x-18200)*0.19)
            print ("You have to pay AUD" ,total , "in taxes this year")
            return x 


            break 
        elif 37001 < x < 80000:
            total = 3572 + ((x-37000)*0.32)
            print("You have to pay AUD",(((x-37000)*0.32) +3572),"in taxes this year")
            return x 

            break 
        elif 80001 < x < 180000:
            total = 17547+((x-80000)*0.37)
            print ("You have to pay AUD" ,total ,"in taxes this year")
            return x 
            break 
        elif 180001 < x:
            total = 54547+((x-180000)*0.45)
            print ("You have to pay AUD" , total ,"in taxes this year")
            return x 
            break
        else:
            print ("Invalid input. Enter again please.")
            break


def super(x):
#Computes super over a gross income at a rate of 9.5%
    super_rate = float(9.5/100)
    super_gross = float((super_rate)*(x))
    print ("Your super contribution this year is: ",super_gross)




def main():
#Main function to pass vars from regPay to overTime and call.
    hw , r_p = regPay()
    overTime(hw, r_p)
    taxpay()
    y = taxpay()
    super(y)

#Call main
main()
```

The output I get in powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\tejas\Desktop\DSA> python salary_calc.py
Enter your first name: tj
Enter your job position: it
Enter hourly wage rate: 23
Enter total regular hours you worked this week: 20
Your regular pay for this week is:  460.0
Enter total overtime hours this week: 20
The total overtime pay this week is:  690.0
So total pay due this week is:  1150.0
Your super contribution this week is: 109.25
Enter the amount of your yearly income: 20000
You have to pay AUD 342.0 in taxes this year
Enter the amount of your yearly income: 20000
You have to pay AUD 342.0 in taxes this year
Your super contribution this year is:  1900.0
```

Comment: So what output did you expect instead?

Comment: I think he means this part: `Enter the amount of your yearly income: 20000
You have to pay AUD 342.0 in taxes this year
Enter the amount of your yearly income: 20000
You have to pay AUD 342.0 in taxes this year`, which repeats the prompt for the taxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your output, I see it asks twice for the yearly income:

```
Enter the amount of your yearly income: 20000
You have to pay AUD 342.0 in taxes this year
Enter the amount of your yearly income: 20000
You have to pay AUD 342.0 in taxes this year
```

Looks like your problem is here:

```
def main():
#Main function to pass vars from regPay to overTime and call.
    hw , r_p = regPay()
    overTime(hw, r_p)
    taxpay()
    y = taxpay()
    super(y)
```

You call `taxpay()`, then set `y` to another call of `taxpay()`. Did you mean just to call this once? If so, try this instead:

```
def main():
#Main function to pass vars from regPay to overTime and call.
    hw , r_p = regPay()
    overTime(hw, r_p)
    y = taxpay()
    super(y)
```

Comment: Okay. Looks like i was calling the taxpay function twice indirectly. Ta!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, both of the following call / execute the `taxpay` function, so this will repeat exactly the same output, unless you modify global variables, which doesn't look like you are.

Only the second line will return the value into the `y` variable.

```
taxpay()
y = taxpay()
```

Along with that point, here you call the function, but never capture its returned output

```
overTime(hw, r_p)
```

And, as an aside, you don't want to break the input loop on invalid input.

```
print ("Invalid input. Enter again please.")
break # should be 'continue'
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Noted.